# How to setup the duration time off a video call

Tags: video-streaming, agora.io

I'm using Agora for creating a video call app. And when I go to the docs of agora [Agora docs](https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/limitations_oc?platform=iOS) I can't find any API to the duration time of a call. Is there any solution for this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the onRtcStats to get the call stats information such as call duration: https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/API%20Reference/java/classio_1_1agora_1_1rtc_1_1_i_rtc_engine_event_handler.html#ada7aa10b092a6de23b598a9f77d4deee

You can refer to this doc to see how to get the call duration from the SDK: https://docs.agora.io/en/Agora%20Analytics/faq/business_billing?platform=Android